# Failed Global Initialization: BadValue logpath requires an absolute file path with windows services

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I am getting this error constantly while i am trying to install mongod using a configuration file. So, I am looking at this tutorial on Pluralsight on mongodb. The person's programming environment going as smoothly as it can. However, i am encountering several problems. First of all, i am trying to setup a different logpath and database path.This is the basic layout of the conf file

```
dbpath=/Pluralsight/db
logpath=/Pluralsight/mongod.conf
verbose=vvvvv
```

My syntax:

```
c:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.0\bin\mongod -f c:\Pluralsight\mongod.conf
//Trying to run mongod using a configuration file
```

When i press enter, i am supposed to get a message that says everything is being directed to this new logfile and a new database. I do not get any message. However, that did not stop it from creating a log file with information in the expected folder. Now, I proceed to install mongod as a service. This is when i type

```
   C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.0\bin\mongod -f c:\Pluralsight\mongod.conf --install
    //using the configuration file to install mongod as a service
```

I get an error:

> Failed Global Initialization: BadValue logpath requires an absolute
>   file path with windows services

I have no idea how to fix this!

Comment: i have encountered same problem and fix if from there https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-windows/

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I was having the same problem with MongoDB's instructions because I was using relative path in the CLI for my mongo.cfg once I had navigated to the MongoDB bin:

`mongod.exe --config mongod.cfg --install`.

Instead I needed to specify the config file's absolute path:

`mongod.exe --config "C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.0\bin\mongod.cfg" --install`

Answer (score 4):

The error message spells out the problem. Your MongoDB confguration file has a relative path, not an absolute path.

Try setting the logpath as follows

```
logpath=c:/Pluralsight/mongod.log
```

Comment: Your answer realized it to me correctly. Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 4):

I got the same problem. After I read this doc, resolved.

https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-windows

1. Open an Administrator command prompt.

Press the Win key, type cmd.exe, and press Ctrl + Shift + Enter to run the Command Prompt as Administrator.

Execute the remaining steps from the Administrator command prompt.

2. Create directories.

Create directories for your database and log files:

```
mkdir c:\data\db
mkdir c:\data\log
```

3. Create a configuration file.

Create a configuration file. The file must set systemLog.path. Include additional configuration options as appropriate.

For example, create a file at C:\mongodb\mongod.cfg that specifies both systemLog.path and storage.dbPath:

```
systemLog:
    destination: file
    path: c:\data\log\mongod.log
storage:
    dbPath: c:\data\db
```

4. Install the MongoDB service.

Important

Run all of the following commands in Command Prompt with “Administrative Privileges”.

Install the MongoDB service by starting mongod.exe with the --install option and the -config option to specify the previously created configuration file.

"C:\mongodb\bin\mongod.exe" --config "C:\mongodb\mongod.cfg" --install
To use an alternate dbpath, specify the path in the configuration file (e.g. C:\mongodb\mongod.cfg) or on the command line with the --dbpath option.

If needed, you can install services for multiple instances of mongod.exe or mongos.exe. Install each service with a unique --serviceName and --serviceDisplayName. Use multiple instances only when sufficient system resources exist and your system design requires it.

5. Start the MongoDB service.

   net start MongoDB
6. Stop or remove the MongoDB service as needed.

To stop the MongoDB service use the following command:

```
net stop MongoDB
```

To remove the MongoDB service use the following command:

```
"C:\mongodb\bin\mongod.exe" --remove
```

Answer (score 1):

echo logpath=C:/myProgra/MongoDB/log/mongo.log > "C:\MyProgram\MongoDB\mongod.cfg"
C:\myprogram\MongoDB\Server\3.0\bin\mongod.exe --config "C:\myProgram\MongoDB\mongod.cfg" --install

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same problem. But I could resolve it by updating the paths as follows. I could see the problem is with Forward and backward slashes in file paths.

## mongod.conf (instead of giving the relative path provide absolute path and also make sure you have "/" instead of "\")

```
dbpath= C:/mongolearning/db
logpath= C:/mongolearning/mongo-server.log
verbose=vvvvv
```

## and then go to Command prompt:

```
C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.2\bin>mongod -f "C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.2\bin\mogod.conf" --install
```

## and then

```
C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.2\bin>net start mongodb
```

Boom it started.

The MongoDB service is starting.
The MongoDB service was started successfully.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem while installing the MongoDB service by specifying the `logpath` and `dbpath` flags directly from the command line.

```
mongod --install --logpath='<my log path>' --dbpath='<my db path>'
```

It turned out that the `logpath` and `dbpath` values had to be wrapped inside double quotes (***i.e. ""***) instead of single qoutes, or otherwise no quotes at all if the paths are without any spaces in the absolute directory path.

So the following did the trick for me:

```
mongod --install --logpath="<my log path>" --dbpath="<my db path>"
```

Notice the paths wrapped within double qoutes.

Answer (score 0):

there can't be quotation marks in your configure file .
way like this is wrong:

```
dbpath="D:/Program Files/MongoDB/Data/DB"
logpath="D:/Program Files/MongoDB/Data/Log/mongo.log"
```

downside is right:

```
dbpath=D:/Program Files/MongoDB/Data/DB
logpath=D:/Program Files/MongoDB/Data/Log/mongo.log
```

Answer (score 0):

In the config file use absolute path instead of relative path for dbpath & logpath as like below and run the command to install the MongoDB service.

```
dbpath = c:/Pluralsight/db (instead of /Pluralsight/db)  
logpath = c:/Pluralsight/mongo-server.log (instead of Pluralsight/mongo-server.log)  
verbose = vvvvv
```

Command to install the MongoDB service is like:

```
mongod -config "C:\Pluralsight\mongod.conf" --install
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error

```
   **Failed Global Initialization: BadValue logpath requires an absolute file path with windows services**
```

as I was specifying log path folder in mongo.config but I have to specify a log file

```
  dbpath=C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.4\data\db
  logpath=C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.4\log
  diaglog=3
```

i changed my log file to

```
 dbpath=C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.4\data\db
 logpath=C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.4\log\mongo.log
 diaglog=3
```

and after that this command solved my problem. hope this workfor you as well.

```
 mongod.exe --config "C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.4\mongo.config" --install
```

then finally

```
net start MongoDB
```