# mongodb Failed global initialization: UnknownError: Cannot get current working directory: No such file or directory

Tags: mongodb, mean-stack

i've got an issue here and i don't quite know how to resolve it with out reinstalling my local instance of mongodb. basically what happened was i had an issue with a local repo and decided to trash it and clone a new one from github. on doing that it seems mongo got confused some how and now gives me the below error message on terminal when ever i run mongod. i can still see my data/db folder with all my collections. any solutions that can be provided on how to solve this issue will be deeply appreciated.

```
mongod
2017-06-14T06:44:26.230+0100 F CONTROL  [main] Failed global initialization: UnknownError: Cannot get current working directory: No such file or directory
```

I saw something in a previous stack overflow question about logpath but that solution seems to be for windows users not really sure if i can apply that or even how to at this point in time.

[Failed Global Initialization: BadValue logpath requires an absolute file path with windows services](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32622763/failed-global-initialization-badvalue-logpath-requires-an-absolute-file-path-wi)